# Replace text in a VSCode Snippet

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, code-snippets, vscode-snippets

I want to create a VSCode Snippet that log some variable

Like this:

```
user.adress.country.log => console.log(user.adress.country)  
user.name.log => console.log(user.name)
text.log => console.log(text)
```

I'm not good at regex, but I already did a part:

```
".log": {
    "prefix": ".log",
    "body": [
        "console.log(${TM_CURRENT_LINE/(.*)\\..+/$1/});"
    ]
}
```

It returns

```
    user.adress.countryconsole.log(        user.adress.country);
```

Comment: The problem is that the snippet is inserted at the cursor position, so it'll go at the end of the current line in your example.

Comment: This can be done easily with the `HyperSnips` extension (which acts like a snippet) or in a keybinding with an extension (rather than a snippet) if you are open to those?

Comment: you can use `TM_SELECTED_TEXT`, select the text and then type the snippet prefix

Comment: why don't you add the `user.adress.country` as field `$1` and place `$1` also inside `console.log()`, type the prefix and then type the variable you want